# Do Wasp nodes only connect to a GoShimmer nodes?

Tags: iota-network, node, smart-contract, hornet

I want to build a simple project with IOTA. First, I want to start a simple local/private Tangle network and then use wasp to write and run a smart contract.

My question is, which nodes can I use to run my local network, because In the docs of wasp they only talking about GoShimmer, What about the other nodes like Hornit and Bee? is GoShimmer & Wasp the only way now to have smart contract?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wasp only connects to goshimmer nodes. Hornet & Bee are for the mainnet NOT development. [Wasp has a really straightforward readme to build](https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp). Yes `wasp-cli` is how you currently interact with smart-contracts NFTs, etc.

I had some trouble with the docker image for goshimmer to work so I recommend just building the goshimmer node on whichever computer you are going to be messing with wasp. Wasp by default looks for localhost for the goshimmer node.

## Build a go shimmer node

Simply clone the develop repo to your `/opt/` directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/goshimmer.git
```

Then the thing you want to run is in `goshimmer/scripts` specifically `build_goshimmer_rocksdb_builtin.sh`. To build you just,

```
cd goshimmer
./scripts/build_goshimmer_rocksdb_builtin.sh
```

Then the `goshimmer` command will show up in the directory that you can execute. Here is a systemd service example if you want to make it a daemon service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Goshimmer node

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/goshimmer
ExecStart=/opt/goshimmer/goshimmer

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## Arch Linux

If you are running arch-linux there already exists a supported [go-shimmer repo in the aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/goshimmer-bin/) and all you have to do is run

```
yay -S goshimmer-bin
```

You have a second topic that is harder to answer, how to start a private tangle. Not enough information to answer this (do you want a goshimmer private net or a private mainnet), make another post.

See the goshimmer docs:
https://goshimmer.docs.iota.org/

Answer (score 0):

This blog post "Exploring IOTA 2.0 Smart Contracts in a Private Network: Developing a Prediction Market" explains the steps to create 1 wasp-node with 1 goshimmer node to run an example smart-contract application;  https://medium.com/51nodes/exploring-iota-2-0-smart-contracts-in-a-private-network-developing-a-prediction-market-c2d81988f75e